# C/C++, комментарии внутри макросов

Tags: c++, c, макросы, препроцессор, define

Подскажите, можно ли делать в **C/C++** внутри макросов комментарии?

И если да, то:

1) Как сделать комментарии в тривиальном многострочном макросе:

```
#define BEGIN_MACRO\
for (...;...;...)\
{\
    if (...)\
    {
        while (...)\
        {
```

2) Как сделать комментарии в многострочной макро-функции?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Комментарии в исходном коде заменяются на пробелы на самых ранних стадиях трансляции: после того, как произошло слияние строк исходного текста по символам `\` на концах строк, но еще до того, как начнется какая-то "содержательная" работа препроцессора. Сформировавшееся после обработки `\` разбиение на строки при этом сохраняется.

То есть вставлять комментарии в макро можно, но для этого следует использовать именно комментарии в стиле `/* ... */` и не забывать ставить `\` после такого комментария, чтобы макро не "разорвалось"

```
#define MAX(a, b) \
  /* Maximum */ \
  ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Однострочный комментарий `//` в макро получится использовать только в его последней строчке, ибо такой комментарий с символом `\` на конце фактически станет многострочным и "проглотит" и следующую строчку макро.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define BEGIN_MACRO\
/* Супер-пупер макрос */ \
for (...;...;...)\
{\
    if (...)\
    {
        while (...)\
        {
```

Ну и в функции - точно так же...

Comment: А если комментарии однострочные...?)

Comment: Я тут мучился с однострочными комментариями, ну я *хлебушек*...)

Comment: Доксигеновский стиль подходит тоже в макросах.

Comment: @AnT А, ну да, конечно же вы правы. Просто забыл...

Comment: @NewView С точки зрения языка это ведь обычный `/* */`, с добавленным после звездочки символом.

Comment: Да, точно, я к тому что понимает, хотя по сути одно и тоже :)